# Calculating ended_at column based on event_time and is_active columns

Tags: sql, window-functions

Here is an example table containing events for a single split test object in the database. The split test can be turned on and off, as tracked in `is_active`.

| EVENT_ID | SPLIT_TEST_ID | BRANCH | IS_ACTIVE | EVENT_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 595aa50 | a | TRUE | 2021-11-11 22:53:08.360 |
| 2 | 595aa50 | b | TRUE | 2021-11-11 22:53:08.360 |
| 3 | 595aa50 | a | FALSE | 2021-11-11 22:34:39.235 |
| 4 | 595aa50 | b | FALSE | 2021-11-11 22:34:39.235 |
| 5 | 595aa50 | a | TRUE | 2021-11-02 23:40:27.001 |
| 6 | 595aa50 | b | TRUE | 2021-11-02 23:40:27.001 |
| 7 | 595aa50 | a | FALSE | 2021-11-02 20:54:29.620 |
| 8 | 595aa50 | b | FALSE | 2021-11-02 20:54:29.620 |
| 9 | 595aa50 | a | TRUE | 2021-11-02 20:31:08.297 |
| 10 | 595aa50 | b | TRUE | 2021-11-02 20:31:08.297 |
| 11 | 595aa50 | c | FALSE | 2021-10-05 20:33:36.394 |
| 12 | 595aa50 | b | FALSE | 2021-10-05 20:33:36.394 |
| 13 | 595aa50 | c | TRUE | 2021-09-15 21:33:58.856 |
| 14 | 595aa50 | b | TRUE | 2021-09-15 21:33:58.856 |
| 15 | 595aa50 | c | FALSE | 2021-09-08 18:42:35.728 |
| 16 | 595aa50 | b | FALSE | 2021-09-08 18:42:35.728 |
| 17 | 595aa50 | c | TRUE | 2021-09-01 23:09:15.596 |
| 18 | 595aa50 | b | TRUE | 2021-09-01 23:09:15.596 |

I'm trying to transform the table so that we get a single row for each branch every time the test is run, with `started_at` and `ended_at` values instead of `event_time`. If the test hasn't yet been turned off, the value of `ended_at` should be `null`.

This is the result I'm looking for:

| SPLIT_TEST_ID | BRANCH | STARTED_AT | ENDED_AT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 595aa50 | a | 2021-11-11 22:53:08.360 | null |
| 595aa50 | b | 2021-11-11 22:53:08.360 | null |
| 595aa50 | a | 2021-11-02 23:40:27.001 | 2021-11-11 22:34:39.235 |
| 595aa50 | b | 2021-11-02 23:40:27.001 | 2021-11-11 22:34:39.235 |
| 595aa50 | a | 2021-11-02 20:31:08.297 | 2021-11-02 20:54:29.620 |
| 595aa50 | b | 2021-11-02 20:31:08.297 | 2021-11-02 20:54:29.620 |
| 595aa50 | c | 2021-09-15 21:33:58.856 | 2021-10-05 20:33:36.394 |
| 595aa50 | b | 2021-09-15 21:33:58.856 | 2021-10-05 20:33:36.394 |
| 595aa50 | c | 2021-09-01 23:09:15.596 | 2021-09-08 18:42:35.728 |
| 595aa50 | b | 2021-09-01 23:09:15.596 | 2021-09-08 18:42:35.728 |

I'm struggling with pulling `ended_at` based on `is_active`. I've tried things like

```
select 
    split_test_id, 
    branch, 
    event_time as started_at,
    last_value(started_at) over (partition by split_test_id, branch, is_active order by event_time) as ended_at
from example
where is_active = true
```

but I know they're logically flawed.

SQL to create the example table above:

```sql
drop table if exists example;

create table example (
    event_id varchar, -- unique
    split_test_id varchar, 
    branch varchar,
    is_active boolean,
    started_at timestamp_ntz
);
 
insert into example values
    ('1', '595aa50', 'a', true, '2021-11-11 22:53:08.360'),
    ('2', '595aa50', 'b', true, '2021-11-11 22:53:08.360'),
    ('3', '595aa50', 'a', false, '2021-11-11 22:34:39.235'),
    ('4', '595aa50', 'b', false, '2021-11-11 22:34:39.235'),
    ('5', '595aa50', 'a', true, '2021-11-02 23:40:27.001'),
    ('6', '595aa50', 'b', true, '2021-11-02 23:40:27.001'),
    ('7', '595aa50', 'a', false, '2021-11-02 20:54:29.620'),
    ('8', '595aa50', 'b', false, '2021-11-02 20:54:29.620'),
    ('9', '595aa50', 'a', true, '2021-11-02 20:31:08.297'),
    ('10', '595aa50', 'b', true, '2021-11-02 20:31:08.297'),
    ('11', '595aa50', 'c', false, '2021-10-05 20:33:36.394'),
    ('12', '595aa50', 'b', false, '2021-10-05 20:33:36.394'),
    ('13', '595aa50', 'c', true, '2021-09-15 21:33:58.856'),
    ('14', '595aa50', 'b', true, '2021-09-15 21:33:58.856'),
    ('15', '595aa50', 'c', false, '2021-09-08 18:42:35.728'),
    ('16', '595aa50', 'b', false, '2021-09-08 18:42:35.728'),
    ('17', '595aa50', 'c', true, '2021-09-01 23:09:15.596'),
    ('18', '595aa50', 'b', true, '2021-09-01 23:09:15.596');

select 
    *
from example;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out while re-reading the question.

```sql
with base as (
    select 
        *,
        lag(event_time, 1) over (partition by split_test_id, branch order by event_time desc) as ended_at
    from example
)

select 
    split_test_id, 
    branch, 
    event_time as started_at,
    ended_at
from base 
where is_active = true
order by started_at desc
```